# Force OSGi package to be imported by maven-bundle-plugin / BND

Tags: java, osgi

I try to package an OSGI bundle using the maven-bundle-plugin (which uses BND).

To run properly the bundle must import a package which is not in the classpath during development (because object references will be passed to the bundle methods as "Class" references).

I do not manage to configure the "Import-Package" declaration in the pom.xml or *.bnd file so that the packe will be included in the OSGI Import-Package part of the MANIFEST. I though

```
Import-Package: de.foo.bar,*
```

should do the job, but as de.foo.bar is not in the classpath (or better not declared as an import in the code) it will not be taken to the MANIFEST.

Has anybody an idea how to force the package to be available in the OSGi Import-Package MANIFEST declaration.

Thanks and regards
Klaus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found a solution

```
Import-Package: de.foo.bar;resolution:=optional,*
```

will put "de.foo.bar" in the "Import-Package" declaration of the bundle MANIFEST.MF even if the package is not imported by the bundle code.

Comment: Where did you specify this?  It didn't work when I added it to the POM.

Comment: @skaffman I added it in the `<Import-Package>` section of the maven-bundle-plugin (version 2.1.0) configuration. I separated the different packages by comma (`,`) and the `resolution` argument by semicolon (`;`) from the package where it belongs to.